# Conditionally read a csv with a given separator and if that separator does not work read.csv using a different separator

Tags: r

I am trying to download some CSV's from some links. Most of the CSV's are separated by `;` however, one or two are separated by `,`. Running the following code:

```
foo <- function(csvURL){
  downloadedCSV = read.csv(csvURL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, fileEncoding = "latin1", sep = ";")
  return(downloadedCSV)
}

dat <- purrr::map(links, foo)
```

Gives me a list of 3 `data.frame`'s. Two of them have 2 columns (correctly read in by the `;` separator) and one of them has 1 column (incorrectly read in by the `;` separator) because this file uses the `,` separator.

How can I incorporate into the function something like if the number of columns == 1 re-read the data but this time using `,` instead of `;`? I tried passing `sep = ";|,"` to the `read.csv` function but had no luck.

Links data:

```
links <- c("https://dadesobertes.gva.es/dataset/686fc564-7f2a-4f22-ab4e-0fa104453d47/resource/bebd28d6-0de6-4536-b522-d013301ffd9d/download/covid-19-total-acumulado-de-casos-confirmados-pcr-altas-epidemiologicas-personas-fallecidas-y-da.csv", 
"https://dadesobertes.gva.es/dataset/686fc564-7f2a-4f22-ab4e-0fa104453d47/resource/b4b4d90b-08cf-49e4-bef1-5608311ce78a/download/covid-19-total-acumulado-de-casos-confirmados-pcr-altas-epidemiologicas-personas-fallecidas-y-da.csv", 
"https://dadesobertes.gva.es/dataset/686fc564-7f2a-4f22-ab4e-0fa104453d47/resource/62990e05-9530-4f2f-ac41-3fad722b8515/download/covid-19-total-acumulado-de-casos-confirmados-pcr-altas-epidemiologicas-personas-fallecidas-y-da.csv"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also specify the `sep` as an argument

```
foo <- function(csvURL, sep){
   downloadedCSV = read.csv(csvURL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
         fileEncoding = "latin1", sep = sep)
    return(downloadedCSV)
    }

lstdat <- map2(links, c(";", ",", ";"), ~ foo(.x, sep=.y))
```

---

Or use `fread` from `data.table`, which can pick up the delimiter automatically

```
foo <- function(csvURL){
   downloadedCSV = data.table::fread(csvURL, encoding = "Latin-1")
   return(downloadedCSV)
 }
dat <- purrr::map(links, foo)
```

Comment: Thanks! This requires that I make the `c(";", ",", ";")` the same length as the number of links.

Comment: @user113156 yes, if you know before what the delimiter would be.  Otherwise, use `fread`

Comment: Yes, thanks! It looks like the `fread` solves my issue!